# Is there a C/C++ Tor API?

Tags: torsocks, socks, source-code

I am looking for a (preferably Open Source) API usable in C/C++, that enables one to send/receive data over the Tor network. So I want to build an application that uses sockets to communicate data over a network, but I want that data to be sent over the Tor network instead. Is that possible? Is there a API for it?

Comment: I don't think there are any well-supported C APIs. There are generally two options for accessing Tor through an API. You can communicate to a separate Tor process using the Tor control protocol and SOCKS port, or you can statically link tor into your program (for example [iCepa](https://github.com/iCepa/Tor.framework) for iOS). If you're more specific about what your requirements are, you might get more help.

Answer (score 1):

> > So I want to build an application that uses sockets to communicate data over a network, but I want that data to be sent over the Tor network instead.

You could enable socks5 proxy in your `/etc/tor/torrc` tor's config:

```
SocksPort 9050
```

Now, simply open your socket to this port, tell socks5 proxy what you want. Ssl/no-ssl, which site/ip-address/.onion domain to get, auth/no-auth, etcetera... So, your task renamed/reshaped from `"How to C/Api Tor"` to `"how to pass request via socks5 proxy on C/C++ language"` which is much more older and easiest task in the world. And of-course there are thousands of code snippets over the network and stack-overflow, which are doing this on all languages in all possible ways.

RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt